# How can I calculate min or max value under some cases, where the some information are coming from vector?

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking for a `data.table` solution.
Where I would like to select the min `list.value` that satisfied the column `V1` / `list.value` <= 0.8.

example as below:

```
list.value <- c(3.6, 3.0, 2.4, 1.8, 1.2, 0.6)
dt <- as.data.table(c(seq(from = 0.5, to = 1.0, by = 0.1)))

dt[, `:=`(ratio3.6 = V1 / 3.6)
   ][, `:=`(ratio3.0 = V1 / 3.0)
     ][, `:=`(ratio2.4 = V1 / 2.4)
       ][, `:=`(ratio1.8 = V1 / 1.8)
         ][, `:=`(ratio1.2 = V1 / 1.2)
           ][, `:=`(ratio0.6 = V1 / 0.6)]

dt

> dt

    V1  ratio3.6  ratio3.0  ratio2.4  ratio1.8  ratio1.2  ratio0.6
1: 0.5 0.1388889 0.1666667 0.2083333 0.2777778 0.4166667 0.8333333
2: 0.6 0.1666667 0.2000000 0.2500000 0.3333333 0.5000000 1.0000000
3: 0.7 0.1944444 0.2333333 0.2916667 0.3888889 0.5833333 1.1666667
4: 0.8 0.2222222 0.2666667 0.3333333 0.4444444 0.6666667 1.3333333
5: 0.9 0.2500000 0.3000000 0.3750000 0.5000000 0.7500000 1.5000000
6: 1.0 0.2777778 0.3333333 0.4166667 0.5555556 0.8333333 1.6666667
```

So, I should have a column with values are:

```
1: 1.2
2: 1.2
3: 1.2
4: 1.2
5: 1.2
6: 1.8
```

I tried to create below codes but failed,

```
copy(dt)[, test := which.min((V1 / list.value) <= 0.8)][]
```

Please kindly suggest on the solution, thank you!

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, the `planned.dose` is coming from my actual project. It is the `list.value` here in the example. The `1.2` is coming from comparing the min value of the `list.value` where 'ratiox.y' is <= 0.8. So take the first row as example, `ratio1.2` is the min `list.value` that satisfied the value <= 0.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dt[, value := sapply(V1, \(v) min(list.value[v / list.value <= 0.8])), by = .I]

      V1  ratio3.6  ratio3.0  ratio2.4  ratio1.8  ratio1.2  ratio0.6 value
   <num>     <num>     <num>     <num>     <num>     <num>     <num> <num>
1:   0.5 0.1388889 0.1666667 0.2083333 0.2777778 0.4166667 0.8333333   1.2
2:   0.6 0.1666667 0.2000000 0.2500000 0.3333333 0.5000000 1.0000000   1.2
3:   0.7 0.1944444 0.2333333 0.2916667 0.3888889 0.5833333 1.1666667   1.2
4:   0.8 0.2222222 0.2666667 0.3333333 0.4444444 0.6666667 1.3333333   1.2
5:   0.9 0.2500000 0.3000000 0.3750000 0.5000000 0.7500000 1.5000000   1.2
6:   1.0 0.2777778 0.3333333 0.4166667 0.5555556 0.8333333 1.6666667   1.8
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `findInterval`. It is vectorized and will be more performant than `sapply` with grouping.

```
dt[, test := list.value[findInterval(-V1, -list.value*0.8)]][]
#>     V1 test
#> 1: 0.5  1.2
#> 2: 0.6  1.2
#> 3: 0.7  1.2
#> 4: 0.8  1.2
#> 5: 0.9  1.2
#> 6: 1.0  1.8
```

Or more generally to handle an unsorted `list.value` vector and cases where the condition is not satisfied:

```
dt[, test := (x <- sort(list.value, TRUE))[(findInterval(-V1, -x*0.8) - 1)%%(length(x) + 1) + 1]][]
#>     V1 test
#> 1: 0.5  1.2
#> 2: 0.6  1.2
#> 3: 0.7  1.2
#> 4: 0.8  1.2
#> 5: 0.9  1.2
#> 6: 1.0  1.8
```